# Selenium python : how to NOT use the proxy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to setup a Selenium application to browse a local network website and can't access it by using a proxy, and i can't find any information on how to block selenium from using the proxy.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

path_driver = "my_path_to/chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver,chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

And no matter what i tried, i keep getting the same error :

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProxySchemeUnknown                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10900/2971943752.py in <module>
     8 
     9 
---> 10 driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver,chrome_options=chrome_options)
    11 driver.get("http://itemep:8080")
...
ProxySchemeUnknown: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://
```

Anyone know how to force selenium to not use the proxy ?

Gabriel